# What is the next step in my proof for the inversion property of MLE's?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, maximum-likelihood

I wish to prove the following theorem:

If $\phi = g(\theta)$ is an injective function then the mle of $\phi$ is $\hat{\phi}=g(\hat{\theta})$.

This is my proof so far:

$\hat{\phi}$ = arg max {$L(\phi;x_{i})$} = arg max {$L(g(\theta);x_{i})$}.

Thus, we proceed to calculate arg max {$L(g(\theta);x_{i})$}.

\begin{align}
L(g(\theta)) &=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_{g(\theta)}(x_{i})\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} f_{\theta}(g^{-1}(x_{i}))\cdot\left|\frac{d\theta}{dg(\theta)}\right| \tag{1}
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
\textit{l}(g(\theta))&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\left|\frac{d\theta}{dg(\theta)}\right| + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(f_{\theta}(g^{-1}(x_{i}))) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\left|\frac{d\theta}{dg(\theta)}\right| + \textit{l}(\theta)
\end{align}

Where (1) occurs due to injective density transformation and $\left|\frac{d\theta}{dg(\theta)}\right|$ is evaluated at $\theta=g^{-1}(x_{i})$ for $i=1,2,...,n$

It is at this point that I am unsure what the next step in the proof is.